# How to convert the specific columns in a data frame as dictionary based on groupby function in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which is like below,

```
df1:
mac            gw_mac         building     rssi
0010403bf0db   b827eb36fb0b   main         -45
0010403bf0db   d827fc36gc0c   main         -67
bf0db0010403   b827eb36fb0b   main         -71
bf0db0010403   d827fc36gc0c   main         -59
```

Based on the mac and building group, I need to frame like df2,

```
df2:
mac             building    gw_mac_rssi
0010403bf0db    main        {'b827eb36fb0b':-45,'d827fc36gc0c':-67}
bf0db0010403    main        {'b827eb36fb0b':-71,'d827fc36gc0c':-59}
```

How to frame the particular column values as dictionary under a new column name in data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.groupby(['mac','building']).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('gw_mac')['rssi'].to_dict()).reset_index()
            mac building                                           0
0  0010403bf0db     main  {'b827eb36fb0b': -45, 'd827fc36gc0c': -67}
1  bf0db0010403     main  {'b827eb36fb0b': -71, 'd827fc36gc0c': -59}
```

Comment: To name a new column name, df.groupby(['mac','building']).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('gw_mac')['rssi'].to_dict()).reset_index(name = "gw_mac_rssi")

Comment: @MahamuthaM ah that is nice

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
df = df.groupby(['mac', 'building']).agg(tuple).agg(lambda x: dict(zip(*x)), axis=1)
```